'ILogger' does not contain a definition for 'BeginScope' using Serilog
I've been utilizing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging for my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project logging implementation and recently decided to switch to Serilog. The migration process was successful, except for the aspect of updating the 'BeginScope' feature of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.
Upon attempting to update, I'm encountering an error message that states:

'ILogger' does not contain a definition for 'BeginScope' and no accessible extension method 'BeginScope' accepting a first argument of type 'ILogger' could be found.

I've tried to troubleshoot the issue on my own but have been unable to find a solution so far. I'm hoping someone here could shed some light on what might be causing this error and how to possibly resolve it.
Any guidance on how to correctly update the 'BeginScope' feature when migrating from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to Serilog in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project would be greatly appreciated.
Code
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Demo.Exceptions;
using Demo.GuardClauses;

namespace Demo.Middlewares;

internal class GlobalExceptionHandler(ILogger logger, IWebHostEnvironment env) : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = logger.ForContext<GlobalExceptionHandler>();
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env = env.IsNotNull();

    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        
        var errorResult = exception switch
        {
            FluentValidation.ValidationException fluentException => ExceptionDetails.HandleFluentValidationException(fluentException),
            UnauthorizedException unauthorizedException => ExceptionDetails.HandleUnauthorizedException(unauthorizedException),
            ForbiddenException forbiddenException => ExceptionDetails.HandleForbiddenException(forbiddenException),
            NotFoundException notFoundException => ExceptionDetails.HandleNotFoundException(notFoundException),
            TimeOutException timeOutException => ExceptionDetails.HandleTimeOutException(timeOutException),
            _ => ExceptionDetails.HandleDefaultException(exception),
        };

        var errorLogLevel = exception switch
        {
            FluentValidation.ValidationException or UnauthorizedException => LogEventLevel.Warning,
            _ => LogEventLevel.Error
        };

        LogErrorMessage(errorLogLevel, exception, errorResult);

        var response = httpContext.Response;

        if (!response.HasStarted)
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/problem+json";
            response.StatusCode = errorResult.Status!.Value;
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(errorResult, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Warning("Can't write error response. Response has already started.");
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void LogErrorMessage1(LogEventLevel errorLogLevel, Exception exception, ExceptionDetails details)
    {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {
                "TraceId",
                details.TraceId
            }
        };

        if (details.Errors != null)
        {
            properties.Add("Errors", details.Errors);
        }

        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            properties.Add("StackTrace", exception.StackTrace!.Trim());
        }

        using (_logger.BeginScope(properties))
        {
            _logger.Write(errorLogLevel, "{title} | {details} | {traceId}", details.Title, details.Detail, details.TraceId);
        }
    }
}

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

check  package version:  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0

Thanks @phiree for your response. The above code does not use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging at all , hence what is the point in checking the version of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions in this case

You are using the Serilog.ILogger interface which doesn't have the BeginScope definition.
You probably want to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.

@wanton I want to use the BeginScope equivalent in Serilog.ILogger in this case

If you do that you'll end up logging from only the parts of your application that use Serilog. Why don't you use integrate ASP.NET Core Serilog instead?

BTW the code you posted is a bit problematic. Literally. ProblemDetails is returned when the request has issues. It's not meant for 500 (server) errors, which is what an unhandled exception is. Unauthorized, Forbidden, Not Found, Timeout all return their own proper HTTP status codes. (401, 403, 404, 504). Changing them to 400 is a big problem for everyone calling your API, including yourself. Resilience libraries like Polly expect and retry the standard status codes. They won't retry a 400

Besides, the framework already handles and logs those cases before application code has a chance to see them. If you use builder.Services.AddSerilog() you'll see those responses in the log. You can enable Serilog's request logging by using UseSerilogRequestLogging to log the request and its result as a single log event

Serilog's specific analogous feature is LogContext:

Serilog.Context.LogContext can be used to dynamically add and remove properties from the ambient "execution context"; for example, all messages written during a transaction might carry the id of that transaction, and so-on.

You need to enable it in configuration:
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()

And use LogContext.PushProperty:
log.Information("No contextual properties");

using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 1))
{
    log.Information("Carries property A = 1");

    using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 2))
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("B", 1))
    {
        log.Information("Carries A = 2 and B = 1");
    }

    log.Information("Carries property A = 1, again");
}


Thanks @Guru Stron for your response. I did follow the same and updated the code : private void LogErrorMessage(LogEventLevel errorLogLevel, Exception exception, ExceptionDetails details)
{
using (LogContext.PushProperty("TraceId", details.TraceId))
using (LogContext.PushProperty("Errors", details.Errors))
{
if (_env.IsDevelopment())
{
LogContext.PushProperty("StackTrace", exception.StackTrace!.Trim());
}
    _logger.Write(errorLogLevel, "{title} | {details} | {traceId}", details.Title, details.Detail, details.TraceId);
}

}
